# Getting element within a known element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am finding the selected jquery tab ui element using the following:

```
$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")
```

This might return something like:

```
tab_48
```

Within the `tab_48` html tag, I have an anchor tag, so maybe

```
<a href="#ui-tabs-4">some content here</a>
```

Putting that all together, HTML might look something like this:

```
<li id="tab_48">
    <a href="#ui-tabs-4">
        some content here
    </a>
</li>
```

How do I get the href of the anchor tag, now that I can get the id of the selected tab via:

```
$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")
```

Comment: do you actually need to know the ID for other reasons, or is the href the only thing you really care about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("li.ui-tabs-selected a").attr("href")
```

or

```
$("li.ui-tabs-selected").find("a").attr("href")
```

Comment: on its own that's OK, but combined with the OP's other code (assuming he wants the ID too) it's a bad case of "don't repeat yourself".

Answer (score 0):

On new browsers:

```
var href = document.querySelectorAll('li.ui-tabs-selected a').href;
```

If you need the selected ID too:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li.ui-tabs-selected');
var id = li.id;
var href = li.querySelectorAll('a').href;
```